# Should accusative be used after "forpreni <ion> el …"?

Tags: translation, prepositions, learning, grammar, accusative

What is the best translation for the following English sentence?

"Those sly bad men took the money out of the pockets of the courageous young man."

I offer this suggestion but would like to know if this is the best Esperanto translation, and why. "Tiuj ruzaj malbonaj viroj forprenis la monon el la poŝojn de la kuraĝa juna viro."

In particular I want to know whether "poŝoj or poŝojn" is more correct.

Comment: Welcome to the Esperanto forum of Stack Exchange! Take a look at the answer by Marcos Cramer at the related discussion "[When should you use the accusative case?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/401/when-should-you-use-the-accusative-case)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*el la poŝoj* is correct.

The accusative can be used with a preposition to show direction. For example *mi iris en la domon* means that the person travelled towards the interior of the house. This is distinct from *mi iris en la domo* which could mean that the person moved around in the inside of the house, although that would be quite a strange way of phrasing it.

However, the preposition *el* is special in that it already indicates direction all by itself. *Mi iris el la domo* already unambiguously means that the person travelled from the inside of the house to the outside. Therefore adding the accusative after *el* doesn’t add any extra meaning and it would be considered a mistake. The same thing applies to *al*, *ĝis* and *de*.

See [this page of PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/direkto.html) for more information, and in particular this quote:

> Kelkaj rolvortetoj per si mem montras direkton: *al*, *ĝis*, *el* kaj *de*. Tiuj rolvortetoj neniam montras pozicion. Post ili oni ne uzu N-finaĵon: *al la urbo, ĝis la fino, el la lernejo, de la komenco, disde la patrino, ekde Februaro, de post la somero, for de Tokio* (ne **al min**, kio signifus **al al mi**).

Comment: La sama paĝo de PMEG enhavas eĉ pli klaran frazon pri tiu ĉi temo: “Direkta N-finaĵon ĉiam esprimas almovon, neniam demovon. Oni do ne uzu N, kiam laŭsence estu *de* aŭ *el*.”